# Deezer Radio and SmartRadio Full streams, API

Tags: deezer

The API clearly says that all user types can listen to full streams of tracks(Content Access Rules) in a Radio/ SmartRadio, I only get previews though when I pull an artist's radio track list...am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full track streaming is only available through the SDKs (Javascript, iOS or Android), for authenticated users. You'll have to use one of the playRadio methods available there.

Comment: Thanks Julaie. One more question... I'm currently using the API on a Cordova stack...does the JS SDK rely on Flash or is there an HTML5 fallback on the Radio methods?

Comment: The JS SDK is Flash based, there's no fallback. The only doable thing is to manually fallback yourself on the 30second previews provided in the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

> > Full track streaming - only available for authenticated users.

1)   Would authenticated users need to  individually sign up 
2)  and would they need to pay any subscription fees for playing (unlimited songs)?

Thanks